# MySQL AVG TIME giving weird behaviour

Tags: mysql

I am getting confusing behaviour when performing AVG on a TIME(3) property.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME(STD(`duration`)) standard_deviation,
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(`duration`)) mean,
    MIN(`duration`) min,
    MAX(`duration`) max
FROM `races`
```

Then the results are:

[image]

As you can see the **mean** is larger than the **max** value. How is this possible. Am I doing something wrong within the query ?

The `duration` column is a `TIME(3)` column. Which represents the duration of the race.

Comment: Please avoid long single line code.

Comment: Why are you using the `SEC_TO_TIME` function if `duration` is of type `TIME`? Can you provide sample data, that will reproduce your issue?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Hey Paul, the reason I am using `SEC_TO_TIME` is because the `STD` function and `AVG` function are returning the number values of the time (ex: `113.293625`) for the mean, and I want to save it as a  `TIME(3)` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mysql manual on [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) says:

> The SUM() and AVG() aggregate functions do not work with temporal
>   values. (They convert the values to numbers, losing everything after
>   the first nonnumeric character.) To work around this problem, convert
>   to numeric units, perform the aggregate operation, and convert back to
>   a temporal value. Examples:
>
> ```
> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_col))) FROM tbl_name;
> ```

So, this is what you need to do:

```
SELECT
    SEC_TO_TIME(STD(`duration`)) standard_deviation,
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(time_to_sec(`duration`) + (EXTRACT(MICROSECOND from duration) / 1000000))) mean,
    MIN(`duration`) min,
    MAX(`duration`) max
FROM `races`
```

Comment: Ahh awesome, thanks. I imagine this also applies to the `STD` function as well.

Comment: Good to know. I ecpected them to work with TIME/DATE - but never tried.

Comment: Well, the manual does not say that, but it is possible. However, time_to_sec() alone may not be appropriate for you. It chops off the microsecond part. You may have to use the extract function to get the fractional secons.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I agree, I was expecting them to work with temporal values as well, since those should be stored as numbers, not as text.

Comment: AFIAK [they store them as numbers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time). Looks like they use a dirty hack, but I'm not going to check the C code now :-).

Comment: @KevinUpton please upvote the answer if it helps you, and mark as accepted if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Shadow what is the extract function? I think it would be important to include the fractional seconds.

Comment: For those interested, this is what I ended up with:
`SEC_TO_TIME(STD(TIME_TO_SEC(duration) + (EXTRACT(MICROSECOND from duration) / 1000000))) standard_deviation, 
                SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(duration) + (EXTRACT(MICROSECOND from duration) / 1000000))) mean,`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by the extract() function, just fell asleep before updating the answer